# How to resolve Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

I have writtencode in service file but, I got  error

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type
> 'string'.

```js
public messageSubject = new Subject();

public setData(message: string) {
  this.messageSubject.next(message);
}

public getData(): Observable<string> {
  return this.messageSubject.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could declare the type in the `Subject` declaration

```js
public messageSubject = new Subject<string>();
```